# Exponential distribution between events

Tags: probability

If I know events happen in intervals of $\Delta T$ seconds between them, where $\Delta T \sim Exp(\frac{1}{\alpha})$, and someone is starting to write down the times in which the events happen at $t=0$, will the **first** event also be a random variable distributed $Exp(\frac{1}{\alpha})$? It makes sense for it to be the case, but shouldn't the fact that we started writing down the times some time $0<t<\Delta T$ after an unobservable event happened be of any importance?

Comment: This is the memory-less property of exponential distribution

Comment: The use of $\Delta$ in $\Delta T$ here is unnecessary and obfuscating. It is much more clear to consider $T$ as an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\alpha$. The use of $\Delta$ here to me is unknown.